# Callback after a thread.Start() finished?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, thread-safety

I've a small question

I've a WPF application, and one method takes some times(it send informations through WCF services). I would like to do this in another thread than the GUI thread.

The problem:

The GUI ask to services, which asks to a datastore, which give a new transaction manager, which communicate with the WCF service.

The datastore objects have the GUI thread as owner.

I would like, in the transaction manger, do something like this:

```
public void MyMethod(abcdef){
//Income with the GUI thread
//Launch a thread with my action which tooks times
//update my objects with the result(Has to be done with the GUI thread)
```

But I've no GUI element here on which I can do a XYZ.Dispatch or Invoke or BeginInvoke. But when I start, I know the GUI thread reference. The problem is that I'm going to have thread  Owner exceptions.

I've some constraints:

- I cannot have a GUI object to do a begin Invoke here
- I cannot set that the datastore has non-gui datastore
- I need that this call is non-blocking
- I need results of the non-GUI thread

Do you have an idea about how to do that?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use [`Dispatcher.BeginInvoke()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms591206.aspx).**

With that method you can execute a function, with parameters, that is executed on the GUI thread. You pass the `Dispatcher` property of your WPF window to the background worker and the `BeginInvoke` method of that instance is used to communicate back.

Comment: Right! But I had to do it on the Application.Current.Dispatcher :)

Comment: That depends. When you are only showing WPF screens on one thread (most of the times you are), it is OK to use `Application.Current.Dispatcher`. But, it is possible to spawn multiple UI threads in WPF. When that's the case, you should take `Dispatcher` of your window and use that to communicate. This ensures that the messages come back to the correct thread.